# pure JS - addEventListener "mouseup" conflict with toggle visibility button

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having a problem with **addEventListener** and the **"mouseup"** event, with this event it is intended that whenever any click is outside the DIV container `Container_CLASS`, it will be forced to hidden.

However there is a `Checkbox List (Toggle)` button, because the `Container_ID` always starts hidden by default.

The problem starts when the `Container_ID` is displayed, ( by clicking on the `Checkbox List (Toggle)` ) this are unduly keeping the `Container_ID` open even when the `Toggle_Visibility` function is called back to act. All of this is because there is a conflict of instructions between the two functions.

How can make the **addEventListener** ignore the instruction when the `Checkbox List (Toggle)` is clicked?

```js
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
    let container = document.querySelectorAll(".Container_CLASS");

    container.forEach((theDiv) => {

      if (event.target.closest(".Container_CLASS") === null) { theDiv.style.display = "none"; }

    });
  });

  function Toggle_Visibility(elmId) {

    var vDivDisplay = document.getElementById(elmId);

    vDivDisplay.style.display = (vDivDisplay.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';

  }
```

```css
  div.Container_CLASS
  {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
  }
```

```html
  <a href="#" class="Toggle_Visibility_CLASS" id="Toogle_Visibility_ID" onclick="Toggle_Visibility('Container_ID');">Checkbox List (Toggle)</a>

  <div class="Container_CLASS" id="Container_ID">
    <div class="Controls_CLASS"><a href="#">Select All</a>|<a href="#">Reset All</a></div>

    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="BMW" />BMW</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Mercedes" />Mercedes</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" class="Checkbox_CLASS" value="Volvo" />Volvo</li>
    </ul>
    
    <br>
    <p><b>** CLICK IN ANY PART OUTSIDE TO CLOSE THIS DIV CONTAINER</b></p>
    <br>
    <p><b>** BUT IF YOU CLICK ON `Checkbox List (Toggle)` WONT CLOSE</b></p>

  </div>
```

Comment: First of all, you should not use `onclick` to attach event handlers to anchor elements unless you know what you're doing. Right now, clicking that anchor adds a hash to the URL and navigates the page to the top, because you are not preventing the default action of the event from occurring.  See [How to prevent default action for an Anchor tag using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5087275/215552), or just use a button element with `type="button"` and save yourself the extra code.

Comment: As far as the actual question, just check if the target does not have the class "Toggle_Visibility_CLASS" before running the rest of the code.

Comment: already found out an solution:
if (event.target.closest(".Container_CLASS") === null && event.target.id !== "Toogle_Visibility_ID") { theDiv.style.display = "none"; }

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

```
if (event.target.closest(".Container_CLASS") === null && event.target.id !== "Toogle_Visibility_ID") { theDiv.style.display = "none"; }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.